# Plotting every day of a timeseries dataframe with subplots

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe whose index is a timeseries. Let's think this is my dataframe:

```
                       Temp
2019/01/01 00:00:00    25.3
2019/01/01 00:30:00    22.0
2019/01/01 01:00:00    22.1
2019/01/01 01:30:00    28.1
2019/01/01 02:00:00    26.8
2019/01/01 02:30:00    25.3
...
2019/01/02 00:00:00    20.2
2019/01/02 00:30:00    27.0
2019/01/02 01:00:00    27.5
2019/01/02 01:30:00    28.1
2019/01/02 02:00:00    28.8
2019/01/02 02:30:00    26.3
...
2019/02/10 23:30:00    21.6
```

Can I plot each day in a subplot? For example, can be the figure like 3 columns and all the necessary rows?

I know how to do it manually,

```
d1 = df.loc['2018/09/01' : '2018/09/01' ]
d1.plot()
```

But, how can I plot all days? And just a range of N days?

I tried using `for` loop but the idea is using the power of `Pandas`.

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

First convert the index [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) (if not already):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Then use either (A) [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) or (B) [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.groupby.html).

---

### A: [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) + [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

1. Filter the desired days with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.loc.html), then pivot the days into columns:

   ```
   data = df.loc['2019-01-01':'2019-01-02']
   columns = data.index.date
   index = data.groupby(columns).cumcount()
   pivoted = data.pivot_table(index=index, columns=columns)
   ```
2. Use [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with `subplots=True`:

   ```
   pivoted.plot(subplots=True, layout=(len(pivoted.columns), 1), sharex=False)
   ```

   <sub>Output of 2019-01-01 through 2019-01-02:</sub>

   [image]

---

### B: [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.groupby.html) + [`subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

1. Filter the desired days with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.loc.html), then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.groupby.html) each day via the [`DatetimeIndex.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) accessor:

   ```
   data = df.loc['2019-01-01':'2019-01-02']
   groups = data.groupby(data.index.date)
   ```
2. Iterate the `groups` to plot onto [`subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html):

   ```
   fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=len(groups), ncols=1, sharey=True)
   for (name, group), ax in zip(groups, axs):
       ax.plot(group, ':o')
       ax.set_title(name)
   plt.tight_layout()
   ```

   <sub>Output of 2019-01-01 through 2019-01-02:</sub>

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. You need to use python `GroupBy()` object. More info about the object is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html)

Below is the code I wrote. It is well commented. Let me know if you face any trouble.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [['2019/01/01 00:00:00','25.3'],
          ['2019/01/01 00:30:00', '22.0'],
          ['2019/01/01 01:00:00','22.1'],
          ['2019/01/01 01:30:00','28.1'],
          ['2019/01/01 02:00:00','26.8'],
          ['2019/01/01 02:30:00','25.3'],
          ['2019/01/02 00:00:00','20.2'],
          ['2019/01/02 00:30:00','27.0'],
          ['2019/01/02 01:00:00','27.5'],
          ['2019/01/02 01:30:00','28.1'],
          ['2019/01/02 02:00:00','28.8'],
          ['2019/01/02 02:30:00','26.3'],
          ['2019/02/10 23:30:00','21.6']]

datafr = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date','Temperature'])
```

This created DatafFrame from your given data. Now, I will extract day and times and add it as a separate column to the existing DataFrame

```
dates = []
times = []
for i in range(len(data)):
     # print(datafr.loc[:,'Date'].loc[i].split(' ')[0]) # splitting the 'Date' column to extract Days
     dates.append(datafr.loc[:,'Date'].loc[i].split(' ')[0])
     times.append(datafr.loc[:,'Date'].loc[i].split(' ')[1])

datafr['Day'] = dates # adding another column to the dataframe that signifies the Day
datafr['Time'] = times # adding extra time column for plotting purposes
print(datafr)
```

Now, pandas' `GroupBy()` object come into play. I will group the dataFrame based on the `Day` column we just added.

```
group_days = datafr.groupby('Day') # Grouping the dataframe based on groupby object (A powerful pandas object)
print(group_days.groups)
```

Notice how the groups are. To extract group names, I run this small inline for loop

```
groups_name = [name for name,unused_df in group_days] # getting the names of the groups for looping, legend etc
print(groups_name)
```

Now, plotting time with available groups

```
fig1,ax1 = plt.subplots(len(groups_name),1,figsize=(10,6)) # Creating a figure with subplots, this is just one row of subplots (since I know these are just three groups, you can be fancier and arrange the number of subplots by using the number of days in the final data set)

for j in range(len(groups_name)):
     plot_data = datafr.loc[datafr['Day']==groups_name[j]]
     print(plot_data)

     ax1[j].plot(plot_data.loc[:,'Time'],plot_data.loc[:,'Temperature'],marker = 's',linestyle='dashed',label=groups_name[j])

     ax1[j].set_xlabel('Time')
     ax1[j].set_ylabel('Temperature (C)')
     ax1[j].legend(loc='right')

plt.show()
```

This gives,

[image: Plotting based on Day groups]

Since you have a time series as the index,
you can reindex the dataframe with numbers, assemble only days by using pandas `to_datetime.

`pd.to_datetime(DataFrame[["year", "month", "day"]])`, add this as a column and then use the `.groupby()` object